# How can I atomically lock a set of keys?

Tags: java, nosql, deadlock, atomic, cas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update more than one row atomically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211399/update-more-than-one-row-atomically)

I have a set of data-chunks stored in a noSQL database. To update the data I need to:

1. fetch (get)
2. update data
3. write (put)

(no direct CAS support unfortunately).

This operation is done in batches and the data-chunks indexed by keys (binary key/value DB) belong to an order which I can use for locking. However I may need to update across multiple orders in a single batch, and I therefore need the possibility to lock all or none (preferably a timed blocking operation).

The API would look something like:

```
void lock(long... orderIds, long timeout) throws NotPossibleToGetLockException;
void unlock(long... orderIds);
```

I guess dead-locking is not a real issue, as I can easily sort the needed orders before attempting to get the the lock.

Are there any libraries that support this kind of functionality?

Comment: The question is not at all related to the linked question. I'm asking for a library that can do locking of multiple arbitrary keys atomically, it has nothing to do with doing atomic updates towards a database. Thedatabase part was just provided for problem context.

Comment: How come this was closed as duplicate? Linked question is about JDBC while this is a general question about locking, irrespective to the underlying storage system. It's actually more about locking algorithm/library rather than databases. Answer to that question is also completely unrelated. Voting to reopen.

Comment: *"Are there any libraries that support this kind of functionality?"* - is really a shopping/recommendation question, which we don't consider on-topic here.

Comment: I can say for the record that there was not something available at the time, but there has since been released this little gem: http://sourceforge.net/p/happy-guys/wiki/MultiLock-MultiSynchronization/